# Mysterious disappearing consistency errors in SharePoint DBs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, corruption, sharepoint

We have a pre-production SharePoint SQL server which threw an 824 error yesterday evening on the Content DB.  As part of my investigation today, I ran `DBCC CHECKDB` on this DB and it came up clean.  Puzzling.  So, I ran `CHECKDB` on all 23 DBs on this server and two different DBs turned up errors, the Synch DB and the CrawlStore DB.

Then, things started to get really odd.  For one, I ran a `CHECKTABLE` on the table mentioned in the output from the Synch DB but it came up clean.  A `CHECKDB` against the entire DB also came up clean.  I attempted to do the same on the CrawlStore but it continually presented me with errors regarding creating the database snapshot.  So, I cloned the DB from a backup set and, of course, `CHECKDB` ran clean.

And, in there somewhere, I also got an assertion error.

I'm not sure where to go from here.  I'm worried about corruption but I don't have any actual corruption to point to at this time.

System is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM, Standard Edition, x64
>   VMWare VM with 2 vCPUs and 8 GB memory on NetApp SAN storage
>   OS: Win 2008 R2 Standard, 64 bit.

Snapshots are an Enterprise feature so I can't create a snapshot (I actually tried) to test the `CHECKDB`. Closest I can get is a clone on the one that's complaining about snapshot creation.

I looked at my suspect_pages earlier today. Except for a row from January (also on the content DB but a different page), I have this:

```
DBName file_id page_id event_type error_count SP2010Dev_Portal_Content_DB 1 65543 2 2 SP2010Dev_Portal_Content_DB 1 22211 2 3 SP2010Dev_Sync_DB 1 54755 1 2 Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_8c648a692b62438888fe7154075a7d2b 1 52958 2 2 SP2010Dev_Sync_DB 1 802464 2 1
```

Errors:

```
Error: 824, Severity: 24, State: 2.

SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x4d448744; actual: 0xe9b1634d). It occurred during a read of page (1:22211) in database ID 23 at offset 0x0000000ad86000 in file 'G:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\SP2010Dev_Portal_Content_DB.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.  

Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "DBCC CHECKDB(N'SP2010Dev_Sync_DB')  WITH NO_INFOMS..." failed with the following error: "Table error: Object ID 0, index ID -1, partition ID 0, alloc unit ID 7998501791723421696 (type Unknown), page (57600:0). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -10.
Object ID 357576312, index ID 0, partition ID 72057594043301888, alloc unit ID 72057594045792256 (type In-row data): Page (1:54755) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors not associated with any single object.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 1 consistency errors in table 'mms_step_object_details' (object ID 357576312).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 2 consistency errors in database 'SP2010Dev_Sync_DB'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Failed:(-1073548784) Executing the query "DBCC CHECKDB(N'Search_Service_Application_CrawlSto..." failed with the following error: "Object ID 453576654, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594055491584, alloc unit ID 72057594058899456 (type In-row data): Page (1:52958) could not be processed.  See other errors for details.
Table error: Object ID 453576654, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594055491584, alloc unit ID 72057594058899456 (type In-row data), page (1:52958). Test (IS_OFF (BUF_IOERR, pBUF->bstat)) failed. Values are 12716041 and -4.
Table error: Object ID 453576654, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594055491584, alloc unit ID 72057594058899456 (type In-row data). Page (1:52958) was not seen in the scan although its parent (1:288931) and previous (1:52957) refer to it. Check any previous errors.
Table error: Object ID 453576654, index ID 1, partition ID 72057594055491584, alloc unit ID 72057594058899456 (type In-row data). Page (1:52959) is missing a reference from previous page (1:52958). Possible chain linkage problem.
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in table 'MSSCrawlURL' (object ID 453576654).
CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 4 consistency errors in database 'Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_8c648a692b62438888fe7154075a7d2b'.
repair_allow_data_loss is the minimum repair level for the errors found by DBCC CHECKDB (Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_8c648a692b62438888fe7154075a7d2b).". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be confident you have corruption.  Sounds like at least one corrupt data page.  What does the contents of msdb.dbo.suspect_pages look like?  Refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191301(v=sql.105).aspx for parsing some of that info.